# How to solve “cannot call method … of undefined” error?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById("start_").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end_").value;
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Gives an error message in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDirections' of undefined

Could anyone suggest fixing this?

Comment: use `===` instead of `==` for comparison, just in case + good programming habit.

Comment: The message is pretty clear - `directionsDisplay` has not been defined anywhere.

Comment: var directionsDisplay; I define this like global variable

Comment: what James Hill said. might want to check `if (window['directionsDisplay'])` before calling... or simply define it else where first.

Comment: @kamal, Even if you defined `directionDisplay` as a global, simply saying `var directionDisplay` does not give that object a method called `setDirections()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing (global var)

```
//var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'map': map });
```

So `directionsDisplay` is undefined.